# Redirecting an URL just for a given referring URL

Tags: php, url, redirect

I have a website (eg. https://example.com) and it has (amongst others) a page called `origpage.php`. But, I do not want the `origpage.php` to open when a visitor who **comes from a given domain** (eg. http://example.net) want to open it. I want this visitor to be redirected to an other page, eg. `otherpage.php`. 
How can I do it?
(I think the "question-duplication" is not the case.)

Comment: You are probably looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `parse_url`

Comment: Are you saying that when a person uses `https://example.com/origpage.php` then keep him on the page itself. But if he uses `http://example.net/origpage.php` then redirect him to `http://example.net/otherpage.php` ?

Comment: No. If someone wants to open `https://example.com/origpage.php` then this page to be opened. Except, if someone comes from `http://example.net`. He has to be redirected to `https://example.com/otherpage.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $domain = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST));

    if ($domain == 'example.net') {
        header('location: otherpage.php');
        die();
    }
}
```